# Show notification on parent window once modal iframe js closed

Tags: php, jquery, notifications, growlnotify

I have a form in a modal iframe window that i create using fancybox. Once the user submits the form then upon success i want to close the modal window and update a div on the parent window with a 'Saved Successfully' message.

How do i do this? I know how to close the modal and refresh the parent window in fancybox. However what i do not understand is how to send the 'Saved Successfully' message to the parent window and update a div with this message so user can see.

I am open to using any notification plugin if that will help.

Thanks,
Shakira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to create a function in the parent window that allows us to make modifications. Do not encase this function in a $(document).ready(function(){ or a $(function){.

```
function updateParent(msg){  
  $('#divStatusUpdate').html(msg);  
}
```

Now we have a function which passes the paramter of 'msg' to the function. The function applies the contents of 'msg' to a div in the parent with an ID of divStatusUpdate.

Now we have an element that performs the event for us.

```
$("#element").on('click', function(){
  window.parent.updateParent('This is a message from the iFrame to the Parent Div.');
});
```

Simply create the div with an ID of 'divStatusUpdate', add the above scripting, change #element to the ID or Class you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response; if i do not encase the updateParent function in $() then will it be a problem to use $('#divStatusUpdate') inside of it? Also is there a specific reason why the updateParent should not be in side $(). Would be helpful to know this for me.

Comment: No. As long as the jquery-1.7.1-min.js file is BEFORE your code, anything encased in jquery Syntax is parsed. As for why to not put it in $() is because that makes it a local scope. You want the function to be global scope.

Comment: it's only work in the same domain right ?

Answer (score 0):

If problem is in changing **top frame** from **iframe** you can create function in top and call it from iframe

```
top.yourfunction();
```

or

```
parent.yourfunction();
```